# Use the SUM notation?

Tags: summation

Is these any way to write the following 2 using the SUM notation?

X*k^20+x*k^21+x*k^22+...+x*k^200

X*k^-20+x*k^-21+x*k^-22+...+x*k^-200

where X is a variable and k is a constant.

**Edit:** I am trying to calculate the above using a standard scientific calculator. To expand the question a bit, can I somehow calculate the same result using powers?

Comment: Of course it is. At the very least we can write$$\sum_{n=1}^1(xk^{20}+xk^{21}+\cdots+xk^{200})$$ What have you tried?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You seem to be summing standard geometric progressions, which can be simplified using a standard method (multiply by $k$ and subtract the result from the original to obtain $(1-k)S$ where the sum you want is $S$). So are you asking for advice on notation, or advice on practical computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using geometric progression formula your sum becomes

$$x \sum _{i=20}^{200} k^i=\left(\frac{k^{201}-1}{k-1}-\frac{k^{20}-1}{k-1}\right) x=x\,\frac{k^{20} \left(k^{181}-1\right)}{k-1}$$

and similar answer for the other one

$$x \sum _{i=20}^{200} k^{-i}=x\,\frac{1-k^{181}}{(1-k) k^{200}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $xk^{20}+xk^{21}+\dotso +xk^{200}$.
You can write this as

$\sum_{i=20}^{200} xk^i$

using the sum-notation.
The second sum is similar.